# Excel - Optimal Mix with Limits

Tags: arrays, algorithm, excel, dynamic, vba

I'm attempting to generate a program that will tell me the optimal mix of candidates for a finite number of positions. Essentially, we are trying to take a group of candidates with scores in six possible test. First, they are ranked on their total effective score (a weighted combination of scores available). From there, the candidates should be slotted into available positions based upon their highest weighted score. In the example included, Candidate A has the highest effective score and the candidates best score was on #2. As such, Candidate A should take 1 of the two spots for Score #2. Candidate B was ranked overall #2, and should thus take the second of the two spots for Score #2. All spots for Score #2 are now closed. Candidate C was ranked #3 and although has a high score in Score #2, there are not spots available. So Candidate #3 must get placed in one of the two spots for Score #6 as it is their next highest weighted score. If a ranked candidate does not have a score for an available spot, they are then essentially skipped. The example included highlights what candidates should be selected in this scenario.

[image: Optimal Mix Example]

At present, I'm using the INDEX function to fetch the column name of the cell on each row with the highest value.

```
Sub Test()
Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
y = 5
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
NumRows = Range("Z6", Range("Z6").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
' Select cell AH5 - first row of data field.
Range("AH5").Select
' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
For x = 1 To NumRows + 1
ActiveCell.Value = "=INDEX($Z$4:$AE$4,0,MATCH(MAX($Z" & y & ":$AE" & y & "),$Z" & y & ":$AE" & y & ",0))"
' Sets active cell to column header with max value
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
' Selects cell down 1 row from active cell.
y = y + 1
' Adds 1 to y counter to adjust forumla for next row
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Based on this, I'm thinking the logical way to approach this is to generate the data in descending order of priority (heaviest weighted score first and lowest weighted score last). Then, write a loop that goes through each row, determining first if the count of the highest score has met the quota/limit, and if not, assigning the column name, and adding one to the counter. If the counter has hit the limit, it runs the loop again, but reduces the range by the first column (only running the next five). Same rules would apply until all counters are full.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to effectively generate the optimal mix? I'm not sure if I'm oversimplifying it or even overthinking this.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here's some insight: hire a programmer.

Comment: Very useful information.

Comment: You have expressed the idea to program it. Did you bump into an issue while implementing it? If you ask for recommendations, then I would say: program it in VBA. If you get stuck with a problem then ask a specific question about that.

Comment: @trincot Right now, I've coded the macro to find the highest value in the row and return the column header (see update above). At this point, I'm determining if a column header count with the necessary if/then statements is the best route to take in eliminating unnecessary labels based on the logic outlined in the project.